# Cauchy sequence version of completeness theorem for real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

This post concerns the existence part of the completeness theorem for real numbers: "Every Cauchy sequence of real numbers has a real number as limit". Could anyone please direct me to a proof of this theorem that

- is concerned with real numbers defined as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, and
- proceeds directly from the definitions of "real number", "Cauchy sequence" and "limit" rather than appealing to some other "substantial" theorem (e.g. the least upper bound theorem).

I already have my hands on such a proof, namely the one in David A. Sprecher's "Elements of Real Analysis", but I don't understand it: it is badly written and, I think, full of typos. I have spend hours googling for another proof, but I can't find anything that satisfies the criteria mentioned above.

Comment: You say definition of real number, but which definition are you using?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you wish to avoid using the least upper bound property of the reals, specifically?

Comment: @Kristoffer: If I'm reading the post correctly, the real numbers as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences (of rational numbers, I suspect).

Comment: Yes, real numbers are defined as Cauchy sequences of rational numbers.

Comment: The reason I'm interested in this is that I'm trying to reconstruct parts of real analysis in a certain formal system that is not based on classical logic. Proving the least upper bound property first is, I think, more difficult, and at any rate less elegant, than proving completeness the way indicated.